# Control CP matrix layout with CSS

Tags: control-panel, cp-dashboard

Is it possible to control the Matrix layout with CSS within the CP?

The Rich Text fields I have are currently displaying like this:

[image: Craft CMS matrix default layout]

But I'd like this specific field to look something like this:

[image: Craft CMS matrix custom layout]

I'd like to avoid using a plugin if possible.

Comment: There's a related feature request here you might want to comment on: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/825

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. To do that kind of change your best bet would be to use [CPCSS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss). It's a plugin but really only just provides you with a way to inject custom styles or a stylesheet for use in the control panel. It's well maintained by a responsible author so I don't see any reason to worry about that one.

Comment: Thank you for the reassurance with the plugin. Coming from WP, it's good to know. Will give this a whirl.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Matrix field to a [**SuperTable field**](https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable) and use the "Table Layout" setting for the field to accomplish this data arrangement.

The "Table Layout" setting is here:
https://www.screencast.com/t/Y3jm9DIr